# How to make NSUserDefaults data last for 3 sessions

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

I have this piece of code

```
 NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];  
        if (![defaults objectForKey:@"firstRuns"]){

            [defaults setObject:[NSDate date] forKey:@"firstRuns"];
            if ([cellValue isEqual: @"First"] || [cellValue isEqual: @"Primo"]){   
                cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
            } else {
                cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            }
        }
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

in

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

in order that the background of the row called "Primo" or "First" is set to yellow for the first use of the user.

I want the yellow background to last at least 3 sessions, how can i do that? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
NSNumber *runNumber = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"runNum"];
if (runNumber) {
    if ([runNumber intValue] < 3) {
        if ([cellValue isEqual:@"First"] || [cellValue isEqual:@"Primo"]) {
            cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
        } else {
            cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        }
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[runNumber intValue] + 1] forKey:@"runNum"];
    } else {
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }
} else {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] forKey:@"runNum"];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
}
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Comment: It keeps being yellow even after 3 sessions :(

Comment: It tells me that `[defaults objectForKey:@"runNum"]` "Use of undeclared identifier "defaults". I'm pretty new to this, how to fix?

Comment: Sorry, I had some bad syntax in there, try the updated code in my answer.

Comment: Oh, thanks, i thought i had to declare `NSUserDefaults *defaults` .

Comment: Nah, thats just extra work.  I just use `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]`.  But if it makes things cleaner and easier to read, assigning `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]` to a variable is fine.  Its just preference.

Answer (score 0):

Use the UserDefaults in `applicationDidLaunch:`

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];    
NSInteger sessionCount = [[defaults objectForKey:@"sessionCount"] intValue]; 

sessionCount++;

[defaults setInteger:sessionCount forKey:@"sessionCount"];
```

Use that value in your tableview session to trigger yellow or white

Comment: Before `sessionCount++` should i insert my `if` statement?

Comment: No you use that blob in appDidLaunch in the app delegate. You can then add that value as an extra conditional in your cell code

Comment: Oh okay. So, i put that blob into `applicationDidLaunch`, then i come back to my `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` and i can put the code i had before or?